# Destructuring react hook results in: This expression is not callable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, destructuring

I'm creating a custom hook and want to return an object and two functions when the hook is called. I do not want to return it as `return {body, setProperty, setBody}`, since I might call the hook multiple times within the same component and need different names for the variables.

I'd want to call it just as `useState` where I can destructure it as an array `const [firstBody, setFirstBodyProp, setFirstBody] = useJSONState({/*Some code*/})`, but when I try to return it as such `return [body, setProperty, setBody]`, I get the following error when calling it from a component:
*This expression is not callable.
Type 'jsonType' has no call signatures.ts(2349)*

My Code:

```
type jsonType = {
  [property: string]: any
}

const useJSONState = (json: jsonType) => {

  const [ body, setBody ] = useState(json)

  function setProp(property: string, value: any){
    let newBody = {...body}
    newBody[property] = value
    setBody(newBody)
  }

  return [body, setProp, setBody]
}

export default useJSONState
```

Comment: it would be better if you could reproduce the problem on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Hmm ok, does this link work?
https://codesandbox.io/embed/muddy-grass-ulv2uc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Soerman it's not reproducible on your test app

Comment: `return [body, setProp, setBody] as const;`

Comment: JSON is *always* a string, it is a *serialized* JavaScript value. You are conceptually handling an ordinary JavaScript object, not a JSON string. You should update the names of things to reflect this.

Comment: updated to `type jsonType= {[property:string] = string | number | boolean | null | undefined}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is `TypeScript inference`. Your hook is returning an array of `body,setProp,setBody` but TypeScript infers the type to be `jsonType[]`, which is the type of `body`(the first element in the array). To solve this error, you have to specify the return type of the hook explicitly.

```
export const useJSONState = (
   json: jsonType
): [
   jsonType,
   (property: string, value: any) => void,
   React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<jsonType>>
] => {
   // .....
   return [body, setProp, setBody];
}
```